# UICollectionViewCell scale cell size while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a UICollectionView where the UICollectionViewCell is getting scaled down when "leaving" the visible area at the top or bottom. And getting scaled up to normal size while "entering" the visible area.

I've been trying some scale/animation code in:
`scrollViewDidScroll()`
, but I can't seem to get it right.

My complete function looks like this:

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    var arr = colView.indexPathsForVisibleItems()

    for indexPath in arr{

        var cell = colView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath as! NSIndexPath)!
        var pos = colView.convertRect(cell.frame, toView: self.view)

        if pos.origin.y < 50 && pos.origin.y >= 0{

            cell.hidden = false

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

                cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.02 * pos.origin.y, 0.02 * pos.origin.y)

            })

        }else if pos.origin.y == 50{

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

                cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Is this in some way the right approach, or is there another better way?

Comment: Look into iCarousel. It's a great library that supports the effect I think you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Tobias, I'll go check that out straight away!

Comment: Have you managed to get this working?

Answer (score 5):

Not a complete solution, but a few remarks/pointers:

1. You should not mess with the collection view cells directly in this way, but rather have a custom [`UICollectionViewLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html) subclass that modifies the [`UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes_class/index.html) to include the desired `transform` and invalidating the layout whenever necessary.
2. Doing `if pos.origin.y == 50` is definitely not a good idea, because the scrolling might not pass by all values (that is, it might jump from 45 to 53). So, use `>=` and include some other way if you want to ensure that your animation is only executed once at the "boundary" (for example, store the last position or a flag).

Comment: Awesome, I'll bear this in mind and continue testing out stuff. Thanks!