# How to make UIView change it size as it scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

I am implementing a scroll view picker I have implemented most of the part but I'm stuck at changing the size when it scrolls.

**I'm trying to do this :**

[image: chnaging channels]

I have got till here and i don't know how to change size using scroll offset i tried many things but failed i need help

[image: my]

I'm using  [SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) to get the scroll

```
func swipeViewDidScroll(swipeView: SwipeView!) {

    //USE swipeView.currentItemView to access current view
    //USE swipeView.itemViewAtIndex(swipeView.currentItemIndex - 1) to access previous view
    //USE swipeView.itemViewAtIndex(swipeView.currentItemIndex + 1) to access next View


    swipeView.currentItemView.frame = CGRect(x: swipeView.currentItemView.bounds.origin.x, y: swipeView.currentItemView.bounds.origin.y , width: (swipeView.currentItemView.bounds.width + swipeView.scrollOffset) - CGFloat((280 * swipeView.currentItemIndex)), height: swipeView.currentItemView.bounds.height)

}
```

I have attached the project to make your work easier understanding my work
[LINK TO PROJECT](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2csGr9uKp1DQTJCS2hsNy1rRkE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you can use collection view to do right?

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: @O-mkar try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063979/uicollectionviewcell-change-cell-size-while-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

1. create a special class for the cells in the slider
2. when the cell is created, add `NSLayoutContraints` of width and aspect ratio to the view
3. create a method to expand the cell using the constraint inside the class, like

   ```
   -(void)expandCell {
     self.widthConstraint.constant = normalWidth * 1.05f;
   }

   -(void)normalizeCell {
     self.widthConstraint.constant = normalWidth;
   }
   ```
4. when the view is at the center you call the method `expandCell` to expand it 5% and when the cell is out you call the `normalizeCell`. To make things prettier you just animate that.