# CollectionView view top cell animation

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I want to transform or scaling the collection view top visible cells when it goes off from the screen and comes into the screen when user scrolling. Should I need to use the custom collectionview layout for scaling or transforming?

Comment: I don't think so. You should be able to implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` and set the implementation to the collection view's `.delegate` property. Your implementation should provide `scrollViewDidScroll()`, at the very least, and when it's called, check the scrolled distance and use that to run your animations accordingly.

Comment: I google through and found this topic.But some one told to use custom layout.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063979/uicollectionviewcell-change-cell-size-while-scrolling

Comment: if anyone need please go through the link
https://github.com/Morshed22/MALayout/tree/master